# What is the best practice when naming a queue?

Tags: queue, naming-conventions, naming

I would like to know if there is an internationally recognized best practice for naming queues?

My question is probably easiest to understand with an example:

Someone uploads an image and I add a message to a queue because I want to make a thumbnail but I don't want to make the uploader wait for the thumbnail to be created.

Now the queue contains a message with the id of the uploaded file and it is implicit for me that the purpose of this message is to create a thumbnail.

So do I name it based on what just happened?

**image-uploaded**

Or do I name it based on what I want to happen to items from the queue?

**create-thumbnail**

Almost like a method name?

Or do I name the queue by what it contains?

**image-ids**

And bonus question ... because I am expecting that best practice is to name it after what I want to use it for, like "create-thumbnail" - so what happens if I also want to add metadata? Then the queue will be wrongly named.

Should I then create ANOTHER queue and call it "set-image-metadata"?

But now I have two queues and letting a naming convention get in the way of my software. Because I probably want to both create the thumbnail and set metadata in one queue trigger because when I have the image loaded anyway, that would be most efficient.

So is it better to name it something more generic like

**image-post-processing**

I am interested in two aspects here:

1. How should I name it in reference to the examples above?
2. Should I include something like the class name or queue trigger that it belongs to or something like that? Because in one way, the queue doesn't know who it belongs to - but in reality in my software design it is very tightly coupled to a specific queue trigger, so shouldn't I indicate that somehow on the queue?

Thank you very much for your insights.

(Stackoverflow might deem this question to be too subjective but I have gained great value from finding questions like these in the past - but for the sake of objectivity, it would be great if you could reference authoritative sources)

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is that you should name variables after what they represent. How a variable is used may change. In this case "uploadedImages" would be an appropriate name.

Comment: Thank you. Now you say variables but your proposal is that the same rules go for queues?

Comment: @NielsBrinch You mentioned "a queue" so I assumed you meant a variable (of Queue type) rather than a type. For a type (or class) you could use the name *ImageQueue* or *Queue* depending on the implementation.

Comment: Actually I meant an infrastructure component. Meaning basically a piece of storage that you interact with like a database - but it’s a queue